# Load JSON data through jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a textbox value (invoice number) to a PHP file through jQuery and AJAX. From the PHP file, I am returning the JSON encoded data. I want to display the values fetched from the database in the following textboxes (Total Amount, Balance Amount) and select boxes (Payment mode, Payment status).

I am not getting the output I wish. Where am I going wrong?

**HTML:**

```
    <form  name="inv_payment" method="post" action="" style="margin:0px;width:400px;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Payment details</legend>
        <label for=inv_num>Invoice Number</label>
            <input id=inv_num name=inv_num type=number placeholder="12345" required autofocus  >
            <input type=button name="get_details" id="get_details" value="Get Details"  >
            <label for=tot_amt>Total Amount</label>
            <input id=tot_amt name=tot_amt type=text placeholder="12345" disabled > <br/>
            <label for=pay_up>Pay Up </label>
            <input id=pay_up name=pay_up type=text placeholder="12345" required ><br/>
            <label for=bal_amt>Balance Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input id=bal_amt name=bal_amt type=text placeholder="12345" disabled > <br/>
                <label id="paymt_mode"><strong>Payment Mode</strong></label>
                            <select name="pay_mode" style="width: 130px">
                            <option selected="selected">Cash</option>
                            <option>Cheque</option>
                            </select><br/>
                <label id="paymt_status"><strong>Payment Status</strong> </label>
                            <select name="pay_status" style="width: 130px">
                            <option selected="selected">Pending</option>
                            <option>Completed</option>
                            </select><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Payment" name="pay_btn">
      </fieldset>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $('#get_details').click(function() {

        //To pass the invoice number and fetch related details
        $.getJSON("get_invpay_details.php", {id: $('#inv_num').val()}, function(data){
            $('#tot_amt').val(data['Total_Amount']);
            $('#bal_amt').val(data['Balance_Amount']);
            $('#pay_mode').val(data['Payment_Type']);
                        $('#pay_status').val(data['Payment_Status']);
        });
              });
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php 
        include('includes/dbfunctions.php');
        include('includes/db.php');
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
                $tmp = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("select Total_Amount,Balance_Amount,Payment_Type,Payment_Status from invoice where InvoiceNum='$tmp'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
        {
            $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: If it's not the output you wished, what exactly are you getting? Also, consider moving to mysqli or PDO, and your query does look weird!

Comment: show us your json response... check in your console..

Comment: can you show your `json_encode($data)` content..

Comment: @bipen The console doesn't show up anything.

Comment: i think you have an error in your sql query... print that and run it.. check if it returns data

Comment: @bipen I have checked my query.It gave me the correct output in mysql editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your json response value populate with `object.data` like this.

```
$('#tot_amt').val(data.Total_Amount);
$('#bal_amt').val(data.Balance_Amount);
$('#pay_mode').val(data.Payment_Type);
$('#pay_status').val(data.Payment_Status);
```

Here `data` is an `object` not a `array`.

Comment: Thanks ranjith for reply.I tried your code but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> I have checked my query.It gave me the correct output in mysql editor.

what i could see is.. you have a typo in your question...

missing  `});` for document.ready..which might be breaking your script..(this should have error in your console though..)..anyways something to check about..

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


    $('#get_details').click(function() {

    //To pass the invoice number and fetch related details
      $.getJSON("get_invpay_details.php", {id: $('#inv_num').val()}, function(data){
          $('#tot_amt').val(data['Total_Amount']);
          $('#bal_amt').val(data['Balance_Amount']);
          $('#pay_mode').val(data['Payment_Type']);
          $('#pay_status').val(data['Payment_Status']);
      });
    });
   });
  //^^--here
```

Comment: Thank you bipen. I forgot to close the $(document).ready(function() { with });.Now the Value gets displayed in my textbox(Total Amount) but my select boxes(Payment Mode amd Payment status are not getting reflected.)

Comment: that should work... make sure you have `data['Payment_Type']` option in your select box